# .env file access token working for API but not another in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js, spotify

I'm calling two DBs -- WordsAPI and Spotify API. For each DB there is an access token/db key, both of which I've stored in a `.env` file.

I'm fetch the data in identical ways in `getStaticProps` and it's working just fine for WordsAPI but not Spotify. In Postman, Spotify works just fine.

Here are the calls:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const wordsRes = await fetch(
    `https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/${context.params.word}/definitions`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_KEY,
        "x-rapidapi-host": "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  const songsRes = await fetch(
    `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${context.params.word}&type=track`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  const wordsData = await wordsRes.json();
  const songsData = await songsRes.json();
  return {
    props: {
      wordsData,
      songsData,
    },
  };
}
```

the `.env` file is as simple as follows:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN=BQDcgHT2IfAXsXXX_XXX_XXX
NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_KEY=a2c92537d6mshXXX
```

I heard that leaving the key at the bottom of the file without an extra line can mess it up, but switching them around didn't change anything. I've also tried various combinations of switching to string format in each file, switching the header key to `"authorization"`, using string interpolation etc. Also tried naming my file `.env.local` (as was recommended for Next.js), but nothing works.

Most of the solutions on SO seem to be about .env files not working at all, which isn't the case here.

Comment: If you `console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN)` does it show the correct token?

Comment: it logs ```undefined```

Comment: Have you restarted the server throughout all of your experiments with `.env` ?

Comment: you can log all of your env vars and check with this snippet: ```Object.keys(k => console.log(`--- > ${k}=${process.env[k]}`))```;

Comment: @Rostyslav nope, just restarted it and now it works. Thanks! Occam's Razor biting me in the ass again.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the code everything looks fine in general. It would help if you restarted the server whenever you made a new file, I believe. Try restating the server. It should work.